# Send Cookies from Retrofit to Rest

Tags: android, rest, cookies, retrofit

I've been working on an app in android studio. I'm using retrofit2 with java and sdk 30.
In my backend, I have a rest-endpoint that receives a Cookie each time it's called:

```
@POST
@Path("/registerEvent")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response registerEvent(@CookieParam("Token") NewCookie cookie, EventData data)
```

I'm trying to send a request to this endpoint in retrofit, but I can't find any class that matches NewCookie or the rest param:

```
 @POST("/rest/event/registerEvent")
 Call<ResponseBody> registerEvent(@Header("Cookie") NewCookie tokenId, @Body EventData data);
```

Is there any way to do this?